# Is It Possible To Override A Core Class In WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to make the sidebar in WordPress be made of a single unordered list. I am about 99% of the way there, but to get to that last 1% I am going to have to change the way that Widgets generate.

To be more specific, in default-widgets.php,  the class called WP_Widget_Recent_Comments, function widget, there is code that generated a `<ul>` tag. I would like to remove that code and just return the `<li>` tags.

Now I do not want to have to do this every time WordPress needs to be upgraded.

Can someone tell me what the best practices would be to do something like this? I am very interested in maintaining a dynamic sidebar, but I do not want to do this at the cost of upgradeability.

Comment: You should not change the core files instead create your own widget using widgets api http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: This is a plugin, you may try this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-recent-comments/

Comment: Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will give you credit for your answer.

Comment: just answered as you said and Thanks,:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change the core files instead create your own widget using widgets api, here are some links for you
[**WordPress Widgets Api**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-recent-comments/), another useful article about [**a step by step tutorial**](http://www.doitwithwp.com/how-to-create-wordpress-widget-step-by-step/) and a plugin here with comprehensive control about their appearance [**Get Recent Comments**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-recent-comments/), hope it helps.